# Nginx reverse proxy to angular docker container missing static asset files

Tags: angular, docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Nginx server running on machine, I set reverse proxy to angular docker app which runs on localhost:4200. Rerouting works well but angular app can't load static assets. Bellow is part of my conf.d file. If I use location to the root ( / ) everything works well looks like I missing something :(.

`

```
  location /auth {
      
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://localhost:4200/;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

  
        }
```

`

I tried to set basehref in angular app to /auth but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need angular container to reverse the traffic, You can use multi stage option in Dockerfile to compile the angular project and copy the dist files into nginx container.**

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.1 AS build
   
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates
    
#Google Chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | 
apt-key add - && \
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable xvfb
    
#Define the working directory of a Docker container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
#Copy package.json file in to working directory
COPY package.json ./
    
#Install dependency library from package.json 
RUN npm install
    
#Copy project from local directory to working directory
COPY . .
    
#Default build configuration.
ARG CONFIGURATION=staging
    
#Run application with staging environment
RUN npm run build:$CONFIGURATION
    
FROM nginx:latest
    
#Remove default nginx file
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
    
#Copy nginx config file
COPY /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    
#Copy compiled project files in to nginx path container 
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 4200
```

**You should add blow configuration into nginx container.**

> nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       4200;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Comment: My angular contaienr is not reversing traffic. I have multiple apps which are dockerized and I have nginx which acts as router.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well and it seems when you change the location to something other than root, it will try to grab assets from the reverse proxy itself at /etc/nginx/html/assets/img/example.png

Assuming you store your statics in the assets folder, I believe adding this may fix it:

```
    location ~* "^/assets.*?$" {
        # Comment out below to debug http referer and adjust the IF statement as needed
        # add_header X-referer-test "$http_referer";

        if ($http_referer ~ /auth/) {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        }
    }
```